# Replacing value of a two dimensional java ArrayList

Tags: java, loops, data-structures, arraylist

I have two dimensional arrayList, and I want to replace the that is set in the program. The problem is, if i replace the value of arrayList by "ONE", it will work, if I replace it by another value bigger than one, the program enters into a loop. I am using the following syntax:

```
arrayList.get(index).set(index2,VALUE)
```

Basically this shouldn't be happening, cause I am not changing anything within the loops, or?
My Questions is WHY? and How to fix it?

the code that is (i assume) producing the problems is:

```
if(mark.get(index1).get(index2) == 1 && mark.get(i-1).get(j) != 1){
                                // Replace the value
                                mark.get(i-1).set(j,1);
                                flag = true;
                            }
```

EDIT: I removed my code, cause it gave the impression I wanted help with the code, i had posted it so that you know what I was talking about. thanks

Comment: This is a lot of code for us to try to debug.  We're not a debugging service here.  Please try to debug it yourself.  If you find a place in your code that isn't producing the results you expect, and you don't understand why, we can help with that.

Comment: You should read the book clean code by Robert C. Martin. You also should start refactoring you code to do something simple per method and have unit testing so you know each method is going exactly what you anticipate. Finally step through the code one line at a time and analyze your variables and values to make sure it is running as you expecting. Posting few hundred lines of code and hope someone else is going to debug for you is not a way to learn.

Comment: @ajb I didn't post the code for debugging. My question is still the same that I have posted. If i want to replace a value with any value other than one, the arraylist.set() method breaks. i was wondering if anyone code describe the arraylist.set behavior. My code works perfectly and gives the intended result apart from that.

Comment: @Churk I will add that to my reading list

Comment: @Deewanagan There's nothing about `ArrayList.set` that should behave the way you describe.  If it's behaving that way, there's something else wrong with your code.

Comment: According to java doc. you can only use set within indexedBound, meaning greater 0 and less than size of the array. Did you get an IndexOutOfBoundException? if not how do you know it is breaking because of the set method? Also the suggestion to have unit testing to make sure your surround code is not causing other errors.

Comment: I agree with ajb - nothing described should explain the results described.  A small snippet of complete code that reproduces the issue could help.  Based on the removal of code, though, it sounds like you may have (prematurely) decided that the ArrayList code is doing something weird and we can tell you that.  But, the ArrayList code doesn't do anything weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got what the problem was! All the initials indexes had a value of ZERO, and I had a condition that was checking if it was not ONE(assuming it will be zero anyway). if i changed it to any other value than ONE then in the next repetitions the condition would have been voided.